# Failed Return Type In C With Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, stack

I'm trying to write a simple stack code and I get this code from a data structure book but it fails when i try to compile.

```
bool pushStack (STACK* stack, void* dataInPtr)
{
    STACK_NODE* newPtr;

    newPtr = (STACK_NODE*) malloc(sizeof(STACK_NODE));
    if(!newPtr)
        return FALSE;

    newPtr->dataPtr = dataInPtr;

    newPtr->link = stack->top;
    stack->top = newPtr;

    (stack->count)++;
    return TRUE;
}
```

For example for this code, compiler says

```
Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'pushStack'  
Error   2   error C2059: syntax error : ';' 
Error   3   error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
```

How can we resolve this? I tried to change TRUE to true, but it's not worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C doesn't have a `bool` data type (C++ does, though). Have the function return an `int`, and return `1` for `TRUE` and `0` for `FALSE`. Alternatively, `#DEFINE TRUE 1` and `#DEFINE FALSE 0`.

Comment: Are you sure? because i'm using Data Structures: A Pseudocode Approach with C, Second Edition book and they write the code with bool type :S

Comment: C99 does, but it's unlikely VS2010 is using that. I find it more likely that the authors of your book are using `bool` as pseudocode, for readability. Or they could be writing in C99. Either way, there is no "native" bool type in C.

Comment: You can add `#include <stdbool.h>` to get type `bool` and constants `false` and `true`.  This is new in C99, so not all compilers (even after 12 years!) necessarily implement it (in particular VS2010 likely doesn't).  A decent way to declare your own `bool` type is `typedef enum { false, true } bool;`

Comment: @AndyShulman: In fact, C99 (which VS2010 doesn't support) does have a native bool type; it just calls it `_Bool`.  `bool` is a macro (`#define bool _Bool`) defined in `<stdbool.h>`.